# Failing to redirect stdout or stderr of an executable in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, redirect, exe

I'm trying to redirect the output of a windows exe file that I received from a vendor.  I don't have the code to this file and the vendor is a little hawkish, so sorry for the obfuscation.

Please not that I'm not trying to concatenate output and error together - I can't get either to redirect.

If I run it using powershell, I get the following

```
PS C:\test>.\vendor.exe
output
output
output
error
error
output
```

When I try to redirect stdout, I get the following.

```
PS C:\test>.\vendor.exe > output.txt
error
error
```

However whilst output.txt is created, it is an empty file.  It appears of length 0.

Any ideas how to achieve the redirection, or if it is possible to prevent redirection in an exe?

Comment: Most likely cause: a bug (or feature) in the application.  If so, there's not much you can do about it other than ask the vendor to fix it.  As a last resort, it is possible to capture the contents of the console, using the ReadConsoleOutput API function.  Pretty messy though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect standard error to standard out.

Try:

```
.\vendor.exe 2>&1 > output.txt
```

Here, `2>&1` says "redirect stderr to stdout" and `> output.txt` says "redirect stdout to output.txt".

Or:

```
.\vendor.exe *> output.txt
```

Here, `*> output.txt` says "redirect everything to output.txt."

The primary difference is that there are 6 output streams:

```
    1   Success output
    2   Errors
    3   Warning messages
    4   Verbose output
    5   Debug messages
    6   Informational messages
```

See [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your efforts, but this is not the answer.  I'm not trying to concatenate the two outputs - I can't get either to redirect.  I've tried writing simple bat files and running those, and I can get them to redirect - it seems to be explicit to the exe.  I've edited the question to try and make it clearer.

Comment: @neilpmas So neither method works?  I haven't seen something that isn't captured by `*>`.  That usually even captures when a program is explicitly writing to the console.  What do you get for a value of `$x` when you do something like `$x = .\vendor.exe`?

Comment: It is version 2 of powershell, so I think that kills off the *> bit.  I ran - `$x = .\vendor.exe` and then tried to get the value with echo $x - but it was blank.  I can use redirect with other windows items - e.g. batch files, but not with this exe.

Comment: Ah, yeah, the expanded redirection options were added in PowerShell v3.  If you're on v2, I don't think you can redirect things written directly to the console.  v2 only supports streams 1-4, but you can't capture explicit console output.  `write-host 'hello' > .\test.txt` doesn't do anything, and specifying stream 1-4 won't help.  You need `write-host 'hello' 6> .\test.txt` (or `*>`) and that only works in v3+.